# Why is this react native web app over-scrolling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

There's a bug in this application that causes the ability to over-scroll (scrolling past the bounds of the application). It doesn't happen every time you load a page, but it does happen occasionally on every page. This is a web application using `'@react-navigation/stack'` and `'@react-navigation/native'`. The application is optimized for 1080p monitors, and occurs more often on smaller resolution, but still occurs on 1080p. This is what the problem looks like.

[image: This is what the problem looks like.]

Here is an example of the styling used on a typical page of the application.

```js
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  masterContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: theme.SHADE_MID_HIGH,
  },
  header: {
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 40,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
  },
  eventList: {
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  eventTile: {
    margin: 10,
  },
  addEventButton: {
    height: 50,
    width: 300,
    marginBottom: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: theme.SECONDARY,
    borderColor: theme.SECONDARY_DARK,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  newEventText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: theme.SHADE_HIGH,
  },
  bottomBar: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
  },
  attributionBar: {
    height: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  attribution: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: theme.SHADE_MID,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: does it happen when you build the project? Or only in development mode?

Comment: We've had a hard time building the project, so at the moment we only know it happens in development mode.

Comment: Sometimes weird stuff happens in dev mode. I highly recommend that you try building your project and see if it happens then or not. No need to spend much times on something that only happens a few times on dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with navigation animations for React Native Web. They're still in beta as of right now. After removing them, the scrolling issue stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **monorepo** pattern and a **cra-web** is included in your project go to the `index.css` file and set the **overflow** to hidden

```css
html,
body,
#root,
#root > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This may help you